# TinyMCE plug-in "table"

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, tinymce

I use TinyMCE plugin "table".
When I select multiple cells, I want to know how many of them, and accordingly carry out some action.

Tell me, please, how it can be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems not possible out of the box. You should consider copying the plugin and add your special use case to the code.

Comment: спасибо! Я нашел способ
$table.find('td.mceSelected').length 
$table - current table